# Как определить названия следующих 7 дней недели, зная текущий? php

Tags: php, дата

Есть таблица, 8 столбцов. Для текущего дня и 7ми последующих. Названия дней в шапке, в строках будут данные по дням. Состояние шапки должно динамически обновляться в зависимости от текущего дня.
Допустим мы получаем название текущего дня. $today = date('D');
Есть ли способ задать 7ми другим переменным (допустим $one - $seven) значения этих последующих дней?
Есть ощущение что нужен массив [1-7] => [Mon - Sun] и как-то его сортировать, но моих знаний совершенно недостаточно, я только начал учиться.
Если есть мысли как это сделать, буду благодарен за объяснение. 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно сделать  цикл на 8 дней, начиная с сегодняшнего

```
$day = time();
$arr = [];
for ($i=0; $i<8; $i++) {
  $arr[] = date('D', $day);
  $day = strtotime('+1 day', $day);
}
print_r($arr);

Array
(
    [0] => Tue
    [1] => Wed
    [2] => Thu
    [3] => Fri
    [4] => Sat
    [5] => Sun
    [6] => Mon
    [7] => Tue
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Своё решение:

```
<?php
$dayNames = array('0' =>'Mon', '1' => 'Tue', '2' => 'Wed', '3' => 'Thu', '4' => 'Fri', '5' => 'Sat', '6' => 'Sun',);
$today = date('D');

    foreach ($dayNames as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == $today) {
    $initialDayKey = $key;
                }}

                $one = $dayNames[$initialDayKey % 7];
                $two = $dayNames[($initialDayKey+1) % 7];
                $three = $dayNames[($initialDayKey+2) % 7];
                $four = $dayNames[($initialDayKey+3) % 7];
                $five = $dayNames[($initialDayKey+4) % 7];
                $six = $dayNames[($initialDayKey+5) % 7];
                $seven = $dayNames[($initialDayKey+6) % 7];
                ?>
```